# Why are fluid BootStrap3 attributes not shown under a browser inspector

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, browser, cross-browser

I have been working with Bootstrap3 for a few months now and I have noticed that whenever I use an attribute like `container-fluid` and `row-fluid` they are not highlighted under a browser inspector compared to their counterparts `container` and `row`. The `fluid` attributes under the Chrome Inspector points to a div with a width of the parent div in pixels but a height of 0px. Using the Firefox Firebug Inspector plugin whenever I inspect a `row-fluid` or `container-fluid` nothing would be highlighted.

I have attached some screenshots of my a simple Bootstrap project I am working on below under the Chrome Inspector. My question is why is this so? Why doesn't the browser recognize the `fluid` element as any other element with an appropriate height?

Screenshot Using `row`: [image: Screenshot Using <code>row</code>]

Screenshot Using `row-fluid`:[image]

Comment: row-fluid class got removed in bootstrap3

Answer (score 1):

`row-fluid` class got removed in bootstrap3.
So if you have `col-ss-xx` elements inside it, since `col-ss-xx` have `float:left` rule their parent `row-fluid`, will not take height, thats why you do not see the "highlighted" area on chrome when you select them.
Just use `row` class instead.
`container-fluid` it has same padding as `container` but always 100% width, does not depend on viewport.

Migrating from bootstrap 2.x to 3.0 [here](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/)